# Keeping tracking of clicked buttons in vb6?

Tags: forms, cmd, vb6

I have an application with multiple forms. One of the forms frmHistory can be accessed from two different forms, frmClient, frmChild by clicking on cmdHISTORY. FrmHistory has a button called cmdBACK on it. What I'm trying to do is, code the cmdBACK button so when frmHistory is accessed from frmClient, upon clicking cmdBACK it would go back to frmClient (same thing from frmChild). How would I go aobut doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a similar thing to what KD did.

I created a global variable called g_whichForm. Upon clicking on the HISTORY button in frmParent i made it g_whichForm="Parent" and g_whichForm ="Child" for child. So when I clicked back i check if g_whichForm = parent or child then go back to the correct form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best answer but it is the way I know how.

I would create a hidden control on the frmHistory, i.e. lblParent. I then assign that frmHistory.lblParent = "frmChild" or frmHistory.lblParent= "frmClient" from frmChild or frmClient. In the frmHistory you check for lblParent to know which form calls it.